# How to 'redeclare' a string pointer that points to a string?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am using an Arduino with a bunch of libraries, therefore it would get too clustered to post the entire code here.
The points that refer to the string pointer are:

```
char* entrada;  //global strings without assigned value declared here 
char* entrada2; //
```

Later, in the void loop, which is the main function:

```
entrada = "some lots of text written here";  //assigning value to the string
...
while (1) { 
funcao();  //calls in for a function, which can't have parameters for an unrelated problem
}
```

In the function, I will modify the value in the string but do not want to lose its original value, so I assign its content to another one

```
void funcao() {
  char *texto = entrada;
  int tamanho = strlen(texto);
  int rtn_ctrl =1;
  ...
  do {
    for(int i=1; i<=tamanho; i++){  //moves every char in n to n-1
      texto[i-1] = texto[i];
    }
    texto[tamanho - rtn_ctrl] ='\0';  //null in the last position of the string
    ...
    rtn_ctrl++;
  } while (rtn_ctrl<=tamanho-(8);  //by the end of this loop, many positions of the string will be '\0';
 return 0;
}
```

The function runs correctly in its first execution. When I call it again on the main loop, however, the string values which should be redeclared on the function do not reset back to 'entrada'. That is, all of its positions are still '\0'.

Comment: You are trying to modify a string literal which should be read-only. You haven't "assigned a string" to a variable, but a pointer to a fixed string.

Comment: And in case it is not yet clear, type `char *` *does not* represent a C string.  Pointers of that type can, however, *point to* strings.  That, by necessity, is the manner in which strings are identified to C's string functions, among other things.  But just as my house's street address is a different thing from my house itself, a `char *` is a different thing from the string, if any, to which it points.

Comment: Use buffer: char buf[MAX];

Comment: Is there a way to make the above operations possible, then? The problem as I see it is that I have to change constantly the length of the string.